# How to set custom file name in uploading file in for loop?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to assign a custom name for each file uploaded from a form by using for loop. Here is the controller code.

```
if ($_FILES['userfile']['name'] && !empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {

    $files = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {

      $filename = 'test'. ($i + 1);

      $_FILES['upload']['name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
      $_FILES['upload']['type'] = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i];
      $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
      $_FILES['upload']['error'] = $_FILES['userfile']['error'][$i];
      $_FILES['upload']['size'] = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];

      $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|pdf';
      $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
      $config['file_name'] = $filename;

      $this->load->library('upload', $config);

      if ($this->upload->do_upload('upload')) {
          $uploaded = $this->upload->data();

          var_dump($uploaded);

      } 
      else {
         var_dump($this->upload->display_errors());
      }
    }
}
```

This is working fine when I commented out `config['file_name']`, but when I set a custom file name all file has file name test01.pdf. I'm expecting file name test01.pdf, test02.pdf etc. Can anyone point out how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the previous answer without testing it.

Please try to update your codes as follows:

```
if ($_FILES['userfile']['name'] && !empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {

    $files = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    //Load the upload library
    $this->load->library('upload');

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {

      $filename = 'test'. ($i + 1);

      $_FILES['upload']['name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
      $_FILES['upload']['type'] = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i];
      $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
      $_FILES['upload']['error'] = $_FILES['userfile']['error'][$i];
      $_FILES['upload']['size'] = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];

      $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|pdf';
      $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
      $config['file_name'] = $filename;

      //Initialize new configs
      $this->upload->initialize($config);

      if ($this->upload->do_upload('upload')) {
          $uploaded = $this->upload->data();

          var_dump($uploaded);

      } 
      else {
         var_dump($this->upload->display_errors());
      }
    }
}
```

Codeigniter does not load the library twice, when it is already loaded. Hence, we may initialize our new configs instead.

Comment: but file type is already available in `$uploaded = $this->upload->data();`, so in my opinion, I don't need to add file type manually.

Comment: Let me test on my server then reply you again.

Comment: Please check my edited answer and let me know if it works.

Comment: it works. thanks so much. so loading upload library and initializing the configuration should be run separately. i don't know why but surely it does the trick

Comment: The reason is, when you load a library or helper, CI add the library or helper in the loaded array. After then when you try to load again the same library or helper, firstly it checks for whether the requested library or helper is already loaded. That's why the upload library was being loaded for the first time 'for' loop runs. And then it doesn't load the library again with new config. You are requested to accept the answer.